# ¿Como puedo guardar un pdf generado en itext en una carpeta especifica?

Tags: java-swing, mysql-workbench, itext

quiero que mi programa guarde los pdf en la unidad c de mi computadora que genero actualmente se guardan en la carpeta raiz de mi proyecto
Programas: neatbeans 8.2 , itextpdf version 5.4.0, mysql workbench
los datos los extrae de mis txt
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ingreso los datos y el boton genera el pdf

private void generar(String host_com)throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {

```
    if(!(txtHost_com.getText().isEmpty() || (txtSn_com.getText().isEmpty()) || (txtMod_com.getText().isEmpty()) || (txtType_com.getText().isEmpty()) || (txtPn_com.getText().isEmpty())|| (txtOs_com.getText().isEmpty())|| (txtNomina.getText().isEmpty())|| (txtId_st_com.getText().isEmpty()))){

    FileOutputStream archivo = new FileOutputStream(host_com + ".pdf");
    Document documento = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, archivo);
    documento.open();

    Paragraph parrafo = new Paragraph("Responsiva Equipo");
    parrafo.setAlignment(1);
    documento.add(parrafo);

    documento.add(new Paragraph("Nombre de la Computadora: " + txtHost_com.getText()));
    documento.add(new Paragraph("Numero Serial: " + txtSn_com.getText()));
    documento.add(new Paragraph("Modelo: " + txtMod_com.getText()));
    documento.add(new Paragraph("Tipo: " + txtType_com.getText()));
    documento.add(new Paragraph("Numero de Parte: " + txtPn_com.getText()));
    documento.add(new Paragraph("Sistema Operativo: " + txtOs_com.getText()));
    documento.add(new Paragraph("Fecha de Compra: " + txtPurch_com.getText()));
    documento.add(new Paragraph("Comentarios: " + txtRem_com.getText()));
    documento.add(new Paragraph("Nomina de Usuario: " + txtNomina.getText()));
    documento.add(new Paragraph("Numero de lugar: " + txtId_st_com.getText()));



    documento.close();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Archivo PDF creado correctamente","Información",1);
        abrir(host_com);

    }
    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe llenar todos los campos","Atención",2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Nat. ¿Qué valor tiene host_com?

Comment: Hola @AlvaroC. Es la cadena de texto que el usuario ingresa y asi el pdf se guarda con ese nombre

Answer (score 1):

**Utiliza una ruta Absoluta**
  El valor `host_com`, supongo que ha de tener el nombre del documento, si quieres guardarlo en la raíz, antes de `host_com` debes poner `C:\ entre comillas`.

```java
FileOutputStream archivo = new FileOutputStream("C:/"+host_com + ".pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

Deberías ingresar a una ruta específica de la carpeta que desees, esta carpeta puede ubicarse en cualquier parte, pero debes llamarlo correctamente. Podrías poner primero el directorio de la carpeta que desees y posteriormente el nombre del archivo (que es tu variable `host_com`) con el tipo de archivo `.pdf`:

```
FileOutputStream archivo = new FileOutputStream("C:/MiCarpeta/" + host_com + ".pdf");
```